# include php nav-bar in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am modifying a script to add my nav-bar.

The script is using codeigniter, which I am not familiar with, so I tried to include my nav-bar. It works but when you view source the nav-bar is outside the html tag.

My nav-bar is located in an included folder of my site..

```
class Servers extends CI_Controller {

// Servers list 
public function index(){

// Header

$this->load->view('header');

// Nav

include '../includes/nav.php'; 

// Main
$this->load->view('servers');

 // Footer
$this->load->view('footer');

}
```

Comment: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#loading-multiple-views

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The is because codeigniter uses output buffering.

One way to get this to work would be to add your `nav.php` to your views folder instead and then replace your include with:

```
$this->load->view('nav');
```

Hope thi helps!

Comment: @Case So you can't move it to your views folder?

Comment: no because this script is in a folder and I am trying to add the nav from my main site the location of my nav is in $this->load->view('../includes/nav.php');

Comment: i just did a blank file called nav and in nav included my navbar

Comment: @Case I was going to suggest that if you couldn't move it :) Glad I could help!